# Finding the difference between two numpy structured arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data set that may contain duplicates. In order to find the duplicates in the dataset I put the indices into a numpy structured array, sort the array, create another array from the unique values and then compare the lengths of the two arrays:

```
data = np.zeros(t_len, dtype={'names':['date', 'symbol'], 'formats':['i8', 'S16']})
data[:] = [(x['date'], x['symbol']) for x in tbl.iterrows()]
data.sort(order=['date', 'symbol'])
data2 = np.unique(data)
duplicates = False

if len(data) != len(data2):
    duplicates = True
    print "There are duplicates"

if not duplicates:
    print "No duplicates found"
```

Now, what I would really like to do is determine the indices that contain the duplicates. For example, if I had a dataset that contained:

```
array([12322323,'IBM'], [12322323,'IBM'], [12322323,'MSFT'], [12322323,'IBM'])
```

I would like to know see an array with array([12322323,'IBM'])

I've looked into using unique and difference functions, but those don't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll just use an array of integers, `x`, as the input:

```
>>> x = np.array([20, 10, 30, 10, 60, 30, 10])
```

With numpy version 1.9.0 or later, we can use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the unique elements, with the argument `return_counts=True` so that the number of occurrences of each unique element is also returned

```
>>> u, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
```

*For older versions of numpy, one can use `np.unique` with the argument `return_inverse=True` to also get the array that shows how to recreate `x` from the array of unique elements:*

```
>>> u, inv = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
>>> u
array([10, 20, 30, 60])
>>> inv
array([1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0])
```

Now use `bincount` to count the number of occurrences of each element:

```
>>> counts = np.bincount(inv)
>>> counts
array([3, 1, 2, 1])
```

So now we have `counts`, which tells us how many times each element occurs in the array. We can pull out the elements that have duplicates as follows:

```
>>> dups = u[counts > 1]
>>> dups
array([10, 30])
```

Comment: For a structured array, use that method on the first field to get a new structured array, then check the other fields recursively.

Comment: Actually there seems to be a  return_counts argument in np.unique, so no need to bincount...

Comment: @ntg Yes, as of numpy version 1.9.0, the `unique` function has the argument `return_counts`.  I have updated the answer.